# how to hook into java static method?

Tags: java, hook

I want to hook some system api in Android, but some of them are static method. So can I hook a java static method by reflection or any other method without tool like xposed?

Comment: what do you men by hook? registering to a listener maybe?

Comment: What I mean is to replace the target method with a wrapper method, so I can read the parameters or change the return result.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support monkey-patching (like you could do in javascript for instance).  The only way of achieving this would be by working with your own classloader and instrumenting the class before you return it -- which would obviously not work for an Android system api.

If you want to intercept your own calls to the api and replace them in some specific cases, create a facade for the api (with non-static methods) and access it through your facade.  Then you can use a decorator on that facade to modify its behavior on the fly.